# is group's unique id remains unique across multiple domains

Tags: java, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

We are using Google Directory API to access Domain Groups of multiple Domains. Id of the group is supposed to be unique for a domain. I am wondering if it is also unique across multiple domain. We are thinking to save information of groups in database with unique constraints on unique id

Answer (score 3):

The group id should be unique across multiple domains.

For example, when you do the GET request to retrieve a group, you only need to supply a group id:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/YOUR_GROUP_ID
```

No domain name is required to retrieve a group (Same for UPDATE or DELTE a group).

Also be aware not to use email address of a group as a unique ID since email address can be subject to change.

You can visit [this section](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-groups#get_group) in Directory API for more information about the group.

Comment: Is there a definitive guarantee that the group id is globally unique?